# Filter data from two variables using awk

Tags: awk

I have following two variables, one variable(`$x`) holes the name and status of few directories, whereas other variable(`$y`) contains only name of the directory. I need to print the directory name from 2nd`($y)` variable's list which does not have `OK OK OK` as its status in 1st`($x)` variable's list.

```
echo "$x"
/foo OK OK OK
/bar OK OK OK
/foo/bar OK OK OK
/bar/foo OK OK OK
/foobar OK OK OK
/bar/foo OK OK OK
/bad/dir NA NA NA


echo "$y"
/foo
/bar
/foo/bar
/bar/foo
/foobar
/bar/foo
/bad/dir
/another/bad/dir
```

I am trying to print the directory name which does not have "OK OK OK" as its status, but getting following error:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{name[$1]=$1;next} ("OK"FS"OK"FS"OK" in $2FS$3FS$4){print $1}' <(echo "$y") <(echo "$x")
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==FNR{name[$1]=$1;next} ("OK"FS"OK"FS"OK" in $2FS$3FS$4){print $1}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==FNR{name[$1]=$1;next} ("OK"FS"OK"FS"OK" in $2FS$3FS$4){print $1}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                           ^ syntax error
```

I am expecting following output:

```
/bad/dir
/another/bad/dir
```

Note: This is a scaled down version of original data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{stat[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4; next} stat[$1]!="OK" FS "OK" FS "OK"' <(printf '%s\n' "$x") <(printf '%s\n' "$y")
/bad/dir
/another/bad/dir
```